# How to query for Numbers in SQL when data is VARCHAR?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cloned .csv file into my database table in SQL,
and example data looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "year": "1955",
        "rank": "1",
        "company": "General Motors",
        "revenue": "9823.5",
        "profit": "806"
    },
    {
        "year": "1955",
        "rank": "2",
        "company": "Exxon Mobil",
        "revenue": "5661.4",
        "profit": "584.8"
    },
```

Some of the profit columns have "N.A.", and also NEGATIVE integers but these values are all stored as "strings" or VARCHAR in the SQL tables..

so how can I query for data that is a number or not equal to "N.A." (Basically I just want data that includes any integer positive or negative) in sql? I've tried ISNUMERIC() but it says I need to do type cast?

Comment: You should have stored the data in separate columns instead.

Comment: @jarlh IIUC, the OP has in fact loaded into separate columns.  But storing numeric data as text still presents its own problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I understand. (The data presentation format above fooled me.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE profit ~ '^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$';
```

But the best design approach here would be to just make the `profit` column numeric.  Then use `NULL` to represent missing values.

Comment: but the .csv file some values is "N.A." so there is error when cloning into table since its not an integer

Comment: How are you loading this CSV data into Postgres?

Comment: Also this query gives me a result of 0